# Is [facebook-friends] tag needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, facebook

There seems to be a user going through [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) questions and tagging the questions with [facebook-friends](/questions/tagged/facebook-friends). I'm not really sure what is the use of this tag. There are many ways friends can be used with the Facebook API

- /me/friends
- SELECT * FROM friends
- mutual friends
- is friend

So I don't really see the point of tagging this when one can easily search for the respective information with `facebook "me friends"` etc

Current count is 50.

Does anyone have an idea what is the usage?

Comment: It seems the user is mainly retagging questions which also had the equally non-descriptive [friends] tag in combination with the [facebook] tag. Perhaps in an attempt to make it relevant, although I don't see the relevance of the new tag either. I have left a comment for him on one of the questions, directing him to this post.

Comment: Seems like the [friends] tag is pretty unhelpful in general; needs cleaning perhaps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLqH.png) definitely feel that [facebook-friends](/questions/tagged/facebook-friends) is useless tag. You're either dealing with the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) or one of the [social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). For each there are sufficient tags already in circulation.

I think the main thing that doesn't sit right with this tag is that it describes an endpoint in the API as opposed to the API itself. Allowing this tag would justify a different tag for every endpoint (not only Facebook). [facebook-events](/questions/tagged/facebook-events)[facebook-poke](/questions/tagged/facebook-poke)[facebook-me](/questions/tagged/facebook-me)[facebook-groups](/questions/tagged/facebook-groups)[facebook-poke](/questions/tagged/facebook-poke)[facebook-checkins](/questions/tagged/facebook-checkins)[facebook-notes](/questions/tagged/facebook-notes)[facebook-links](/questions/tagged/facebook-links)[facebook-videos](/questions/tagged/facebook-videos)
Well... we can all see what happened there...
**Let's not let an overflow like this get into the tag lists!**
<sub><sub>Yes... It's purposefully overflowing...</sub></sub>

These are indeed all tags that are related to the Facebook API. I'm not saying that we only need one main tag, only that we don't need a tag for every endpoint or FQL table.

Comment: Sounds absolutely right. Burninate it :).

Comment: `facebook-partridge-in-a-pear-tree`...

Comment: @cha - that's a good one! but I don't think it would fit :/

Comment: @Mar - actually the overflowing tags were there on purpose to demonstrate what would happen if we allowed all those tags to exist... :P

Comment: `[facebook-overflow]`

Answer (score -4):

1. Currently there are 213 questions tagged with [friends](/questions/tagged/friends).
2. 104 questions tagged with [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) + [friends](/questions/tagged/friends).
3. And remaining questions are regarding C++, Google+, Database related, etc.

Most of the Facebook operations are done on friends in Facebook in app development of PHP, C#, android, IOS, etc.

And there are 34515 questions [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) are tagged. I am sure 1000 questions can become regarding [facebook-friends](/questions/tagged/facebook-friends). Tags are there for identifying questions vastly. Facebook-friends concept is very needed in Facebook apps. That's why I created it.

*Note: I don't have any personal benefit behind this tag. If you see any harms with this tag, be calm, please give comments. I will definitely answer you.*

Comment: The [friends] tag in my opinion is a very non-descriptive tag. Making it [facebook-friends] does not change that at all. As @lix says, using a Facebook technology/API related tag where appropriate is far more useful.

Comment: @Bart: [facebook-friends] is very useful concept. You should ask to any facebook api developer. At Lix: Don't you think facebook-friends is vast concept in development of fb apps? If large amount of questions can be tagged with this tag, how can this tag be not fruitful?

Comment: By that line of argument, [programming] would be a useful tag, since every question on Stack Overflow are related to programming. Tags should have a good scope and purpose; in this case, [facebook-friends] serves little purpose, since there are many different and unrelated ways of programmatically looking at Facebook friends.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk No. The specific technology used is of interest as a tag. That you apply that to the concept of a "friend" can easily be described within your question. We don't need a tag for that IMHO.

Comment: @waiwai933: I thought there is good scope for [facebook-friends]. Stackoverflow will be only concerning different but programmatic ways for looking at Facebook friends. And will help in finding similar problems fastly. Because I suffered a lot while development of apps regarding same.

Comment: It **is** a vast concept. Too vast (IMO) for one tag because there are different ways to access that data. The Gaph API or FQL... For both the Graph API and FQL there are already tags and there is no real difference between accessing friends data or events data or groups data. If you are dealing with Facebook friends, it would be enough to include the API or FQL tags...

Comment: @Lix : If people can tag [facebook] tagged questions with [friends] tag then why not to have [facebook-friends] tag? It will be more easy to understanding topic also. Tags are for vast concepts. Same like [facebook-graph-api] is vast concept.

Comment: If I see a question tagged with `[friends]` it'll get removed instantly. That tag is even worse. It really means nothing...

Comment: @Lix : I agree with that. That's why I have removed [friends] tag of some questions and added [facebook-friends] instead of it. :( I felt it is better than that. :( And will help in understanding area of concern in question.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk You haven't actually given any reasons why it's beneficial.  You've just stated that it's beneficial, or that it's better, or that it's helpful, you haven't stated *why* or *how*.  Who would want to search for questions in such a tag?  Who would want to subscribe to such a tag?  Could that desirable behavior be achieved in any other means?

Comment: @Servy: 1. I have explained it is helpful for vast concept facebook friends. New facebook developers are tagging question with [friends] tag. Rather than that [facebook-friends] tag will be more helpful. 2. Facebook developers wants to search for such tag. 3. Facebook developers wants to subscribe for such tag. 4. Currently facebook developers tagging questions with [facebook]+[friends] tag. Can you give any other good way than this?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk People in this thread have been saying that the "friends" tag is just as useless as "facebook friends".  It doesn't matter which is better, neither should be used.  What is your reasoning for assuming facebook developers would ever need or want to search or subscribe on such a tag?  Once again you're asserting the result without providing any evidence or reasoning.  Anyone can make wild assertions, it's backing them up that actually makes an argument.

Comment: @Servy: searching or subscribing is individual's problem. I won't search for tag [C#] or [java]. Facebook developers will search with tag [facebook-friends] tag. I have made argument that questions are being tagged with [friends] tag with facebook. So it's better to have that tag. It's big debate regarding this tag. I will confirm with this some other senior members in Facebook. I am still not satisfied with removing this tag. :(

Comment: @SomnathMuluk As shown in this thread, only a small percentage of facebook related questions are actually being tagged with either tag, so clearly most people asking those types of questions didn't feel that tag was relevant.  There are also not very many people subscribing to either of those tags.  As for C# or Java, I didn't say *everyone* needs to be able to use *every* tag, merely that there are enough people wanting to use them for them to be valuable.  I don't need to theorize for those tags, the existing stats demonstrate it already with the number of subscribers they have.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Could you please stop tagging questions with [facebook-friends]? I see you have continued despite the votes on this question indicating that this might not be a good tag. By now we have 49 question with the tag rather than the initial 30. I don't want this to turn into a bigger cleanup. If you need more consensus on this issue, I'll slap a bounty on this question for more input. But please don't single-handedly take the decision to keep retagging  questions the way you've done.